# Is there any open source software for converting SQL statements to LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, open-source

Is there any open source software for converting SQL statements to LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no open source product, but there is an inexpensive commercial product that will do this. The product is named Linqer. It runs about $60. It has worked very well for us. It's been able to convert almost any type of SQL statement to a Linq query.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert SQL statements to LINQ queries without having an object model. LINQ queries objects, while SQL queries relational data, so a mapping is necessary between the two worlds.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [T4Toolbox](https://github.com/olegsych/T4Toolbox) - an open source tool on CodePlex that can generate SQL schemas from LINQ and LINQ schema from SQL. Maybe it won't fulfill 100% of your needs, but it's open sourced and therefore extendable.